# Why using generic type be considered as using as value in generic class?

Tags: typescript, generics

Why compiler complains the following codes `T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`:

```
class Factory<T> {
    create(TCreator: (new () => T)): T {
         return new TCreator();
    }

    test(json: string) {
        // compile error here:
        //          T' only refers to a type, but
        //          is being used as a value here
        let a: T = this.create(T);

        ...
    }
}
```

I don't know.. Shouldn't `T` be a generic `type` in the class Factory? And can T be used as the argument of function "create" which has a parameter type as the same as T's constructor type.

---

I think what I want to do is to create an instance of T in the class Factory. I have tried like `let a2: T = new T();` but ran into the same compile error.

Comment: Because you're using it as a value: `this.create(T)`.

Comment: How can I create an instance of T in the class Factory? I tried `let a2: T = new T();` but have the same compile error.

Comment: Yes, that's still treating T as a value. How _is_ Factory supposed to know how to create it? Maybe you should instantiate it with the constructor, `constructor(private creator: new() => T) {}`.

Comment: TypeScript adds static types only in development mode. After you compile your code to pure JS, types will be erased by TS compilator. You can treat types as comments. Comments does not affect your logic, right? Same wih types. There are two scopes: type scope and value scope. You can' use types in `value scope`, because `value scope` is what you have in runtime.Here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#typescript-a-static-type-checker you can find more information

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when used with a generic type within a class, you need to do it like this:

```
class Factory<T> {
  constructor(private TCreator: new () => T) {}

  test() {
    const t: T = new this.TCreator();
  }
}
```

It's not intuitive but it works. Any other way I tried, I ran into the same TS2693 error.

However, when outside of a class, the approach with a `create` function (as used in the question) works, as outlined in [the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics).

Comment: The `new ...` expression can be simplified with `Type` imported from *'@angular/core'*, e.g. `constructor(private TCreator: Type<T>) {}` .